# want to redirect to page after the action is dispatched in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, react-redux, react-hooks

im trying to history.push to pages depending on whether student.detail is populated or not, but seems like that the dispatch action is not completed and the if block code runs and hence it history.push to the wrong page. I want it to complete the dispatch action, populate the student reducer and the execute if block, check student reducer state and then redirect.

```
const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
const student = useSelector((state) => state.student);
useEffect(() => {
const id = auth.user.user;
dispatch(getStudent(id));

if (auth.authenticate) {
  if (auth.user.user_type.is_student == true) {
    if (student.detail && student.detail.length > 0) {
     history.push('/student/classes')
    } else {
      history.push('/student/profile')
    }
  } else {
    history.push('/faculty/classes')
  }
}

}, [auth.authenticate]);
```

can anybody please help me with it

Comment: you can have two useEffect, on would be called on mount that dispatches the student details and another one which can be the one you have in the description, will check for authenticate dependency and trigger history.

Answer (score 0):

Since API calls are asynchronous you can add an *await* or *then* to wait for the response and then perform the upcoming actions

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function authenticateUser(){
  const id = auth.user.user;
  await dispatch(getStudent(id));

  if (auth.authenticate) {
    if (auth.user.user_type.is_student == true) {
      if (student.detail && student.detail.length > 0) {
       history.push('/student/classes')
      } else {
        history.push('/student/profile')
      }
    } else {
      history.push('/faculty/classes')
   }
  }
 }
 authenticateUser()
}, [auth.authenticate]);
```

Or use a *then*  as

```
const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
const student = useSelector((state) => state.student);
useEffect(() => {
const id = auth.user.user;
dispatch(getStudent(id)).then(() => {
      if (auth.authenticate) {
       if (auth.user.user_type.is_student == true) {
         if (student.detail && student.detail.length > 0) {
          history.push('/student/classes')
         } else {
           history.push('/student/profile')
          }
      } else {
    history.push('/faculty/classes')
  }
}    })
}, [auth.authenticate]);
```